# for x,y in function(): - Explain the python for loop structure

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

Anyone please explain the line of code

```
    es_question = (q.as_elasticsearch_dict() for q in questions)
    for ok, result in streaming_bulk(
        get_client(),
        es_question,
        index = settings.ES_INDEX,
        raise_on_error = False
    ):
        if not ok:
            all_ok = False
            action, result = result.popitem()
            logger.error(FAILED_TO_LOAD_ERROR.format(result['_id'], result))
```

I want to know what the for loop does on es_questions and the explanation for line of code below es_question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Part 1 - Generator Expression

```py
es_question = (q.as_elasticsearch_dict() for q in questions)
```

Is not a true for loop and is what is called a list comprehension. In this case, because it is in parentheses and not in brackets, it is actually a generator expression.

Resources for these can be found at: [List comprehension](https://medium.com/better-programming/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b) and [generator expression](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/Generators_and_Comprehensions.html).

### Part 2 - For Loop

Your question is on the line of code which is:

```py
    for ok, result in streaming_bulk(
        get_client(),
        es_question,
        index = settings.ES_INDEX,
        raise_on_error = False
    ):
```

Let's look at a simpler example first:

```py
my_list=["a","b","c","d"]
for x in my_list:
    print(x)
```

This will loop over the values in `my_list` assigning those values to the variable `x`. Now let's look at a slightly more complicated example.

```py
my_list=[("a",1),("b",2),("c",3),("d",4)]
for x,y in my_list:
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

In this case, the for loop is still looping over each of the 4 items in `my_list`, but it is also doing a [tuple unpacking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/), so the variable x gets the value of the first item in the tuple (the letter) and the variable y gets the value of the second item in the tuple (the number).

Finally, one other thing to look at:

```py
streaming_bulk(
        get_client(),
        es_question,
        index = settings.ES_INDEX,
        raise_on_error = False)
```

This is simply a function call (Spread out over multiple lines). This function either returns a list/tuple of lists/tuples (which have two values each) similar to my last example, or this function is a generator function which yields two values each time through the loop.